# What is the difference between adding an .XLAM file as an Excel add-in, and adding it as a reference in the VBA Editor

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

In Excel we can add an add-in via File - Options - Add-Ins - Excel Add-Ins - Go - Browse

[image]

This allows you to use UDFs stored inside the .xlam file. More specifically, if you click Alt-F11 to go into VBA screen, you will see the modules from this .XLAM showing up in the left pane.

[image]

At the same time, we can add a reference to the same file via VBA.
[image]

Now you will see it appearing as a reference at the left pane.

[image]

What is the difference in the two approaches?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: @BigBen just wondering whether I have to do both to use the codes in my .xlam files.

Comment: How do you plan to use the code in your xlam? Within another module, or for example as a user-defined function called from a cell?

Comment: @BigBen, both using UDFs and calling procedures